# Mysql request - specific time span (unix time stamp)

Tags: php, mysql

Here is the code to select all orders placed on November 25th:

```
$start = strtotime('2015-11-25 00:00:00'); // 1448409600
$end = strtotime('2015-11-25 23:59:59'); // 1448495999

SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE `time-placed` BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end'
```

Despite the fact the code works well and does what it should - is there a better solution? I feel there is *supposed to be* a more elegant way. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's better solution in my point of view, I do the same in these type of problems because `strtotime()` converts the date and time into exact value which is easy to compare..

Answer (score 0):

You can use these way more easier :-

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE DATE(`timestamp`) = CURDATE()
```

It may help you.